# Laravel js Error GET http://localhost:8000/admin/product/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

Good morning I write because I have the following problem:

[image]

on my home page the js files are loaded correctly but when i enter another page and it is called via "@extends ('admin.layout.admin')" the nav bar will no longer load .js files ... please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvwyA.jpg)

Comment: Any code to look at?

Comment: Without have seeing the code, I bet this is a "relative path"-issue (not starting the path to the static files with a `/` in the HTML).

Comment: @kerbholz   <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: Please try <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::to('/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>

Comment: ...or just `<script src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"...` (with a `/` at the start of the paths).

Comment: Maybe the [asset() helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-asset) can help out here

Comment: Good Magnus Eriksson ora funziona !!! Grazie Youuuu

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

> asset

method to load your js file in your code？
put your js file under "public" directory and
try

> asset("your js file name")

Or try to use absolutely path

Answer (score 0):

put jquery-3.2.1.min.js file in public/js folder.

link jquery-3.2.1.min.js in head tag.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```